# Minimizing the median, integer programming

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

Suppose we want to 
$ min_i$  median$(a_i)$

$a_i$ are real numbers

Does someone know how to pose this as an integer programming problem or point me in the direction of a resource?

Comment: If $a_i$ are real numbers, the median of them is a constant, what is there to minimize? Or are you minimizing over different $a_i$, in which case, what are the possible ranges of $a_i$? If $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ is unrestricted, the problem is unbounded below, by driving all $a_i \to -\infty$.

Comment: Sort of you can think I'm doing $min_{x_i} median (a_i(x_i))$. The Things I'm taking medians of are functions of the $x_i$

Comment: @Vogster, The median is minimized when each of its arguments are separately minimized, so if your problem is you are given $n$ one-variable functions $f_1,\ldots, f_n$ and asked to find $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ such that the median of the $f_i(a_i)$ is minimized, the answer is to find the minimum of each $f_i$ separately. Or is each $f_i$ a function of all $n$ variables?

Comment: To take a median, you need a set, a way of comparing members of the set (a "less than" relation), and a way of "counting" the members of the set so you can distinguish the "lower half" of the set from the "upper half". The question and comments do not make it clear that you have any of those things. It's also not clear how $\min_{x_i}$ would be different from $\min_i$ (if each $i$ in whatever set $i$ comes from has a corresponding $x_i,$ then trying each $i$ means you try each $x_i$).

Comment: @user326210 its a function of all n variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Removing a simpler model which was incorrect.

The way median

```
y = median(a)
```

is implemented in the optimization modelling toolbox YALMIP is roughly by (writing in MATLAB pseudo code)

```
y = s(length(a)/2); s = sort(a);
```

Hence, to model median we need to model sort. This can be done by introducing a binary matrix Z with

```
s = Z*a, sum(Z) = 1, sum(Z') = 1, diff(s) >= 0
```

and we're down to model binary times continuous, which is done using standard big-M methods.

Comment: Johan, could you be a bit more specific about the big-M methods that can be used here? When I do a search, all that comes up in this context is MIQCP methods. Is this what you are referring to, or are there simpler methods?

Comment: In the final paragraph here https://yalmip.github.io/command/binmodel/. Note that I am not saying that this model is the best way to represent median using an integer programming, it is just one simple

Answer (score 0):

Given *bounded* variables $a_{1},\dots,a_{N}$ subject to some
constraints, you can minimize their median with $N$ additional binary
variables $z_{1},\dots,z_{N}$ and one additional continuous variable
$y$ if $N$ is odd (or if you are a bit sloppy about the definition
of ``median''). You minimize $y$ subject to the constraints $y\ge a_{i}-M_{i}z_{i},\, i=1,\dots,N$
and $\sum_{i=1}^{N}z_{i}=\left\lfloor \frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor $,
where the $M_{i}$ are suitably large constants. The constraint force
$y$ to be greater than or equal to $\left\lceil \frac{N}{2}\right\rceil $
of the $a_{i}$; the objective will result in those being the $\left\lceil \frac{N}{2}\right\rceil $
smallest of them and in $y$ being no bigger than the largest of that
set, making $y$ the median.

If $N$ is even and $a_{(1)},\dots,a_{(N)}$ is the order statistic
of the $a$ variables, the median is technically $(a_{\left(\left\lfloor \frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor \right)}+a_{\left(\left\lceil \frac{N}{2}\right\rceil \right)})/2$.
If you can live with using $a_{\left(\left\lfloor \frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor \right)}$
as the ``median'', the above should work. Otherwise, you need a
second set of binary variables ($w_{1},\dots,w_{N}$) and a second
continuous variable (replace $y$ with $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$). You
minimize $(y_{1}+y_{2})/2$ subject to the constraints
\begin{align*}
y_{1} & \ge a_{i}-M_{i}z_{i}\quad\forall i\\
y_{2} & \ge a_{i}-M_{i}w_{i}\quad\forall i\\
\sum_{i=1}^{N}z_{i} & =\frac{N}{2}-1\\
\sum_{i=1}^{N}w_{i} & =\frac{N}{2}
\end{align*}
where the $M_{i}$ are as above. The constraints force $y_{1}$ to
be at least as large as $\frac{N}{2}+1$ of the $a_{i}$ and $y_{2}$
to be at least as large as $\frac{N}{2}$ of them. The minimum objective
value will occur when $y_{1}=a_{\left(\frac{N}{2}+1\right)}$ and $y_{2}=a_{\left(\frac{N}{2}\right)}$.